# Call php function with js var

Tags: javascript, php

is possible to call a php function with a js var?
for example `<?php print title(showResult(id); ?>`

```
function showResult(id)
        {
              swal({
                 position: "top-end",
                 type: "success",
                 title: `<?php print title('+id+'); ?>  ${id}`,  
                 icon: 'success',
                 confirmButtonText: '<?php print $lang['accept']; ?>',
                 showConfirmButton: true,
              });
        }
```

Comment: there is no PHP interpreter in any browsers

Comment: You can make an AJAX request to a PHP script and receive its response.  But you can't directly interpret PHP client-side in the web browser, no.  In many cases it's worth considering if you need the functionality in PHP code or should just implement it in JavaScript code.

Comment: As PHP runs on the server and JS on the client: No. There's no direct way of communication between JS an PHP. (The only way could be AJAX-Requests)

Comment: is possible to request from a php file with sweetalert? demo.php

Comment: Request what? As mentioned above,.anytime you can run an ajax request,.you can call some php code